# Calculating the difference between two filters in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an Excel sheet with data in the following format

```html
UploadDate Grant Family Project Officer
05/04/2019 00J90301 AA 
05/04/2019 01J32201 AA 
05/04/2019 97891601 AA 
05/04/2019 00406918 AB 
05/04/2019 00406015 AC 
05/04/2019 00406515 AC 
05/04/2019 00406715 AC 
05/04/2019 00406815 AC 
05/04/2019 00526416 AC 
05/04/2019 00571110 AC 
05/04/2019 00D28115 AC 
05/04/2019 00D28215 AC 
05/04/2019 00D28315 AC 
05/04/2019 00D28415 AC 
05/04/2019 00D29215 AC 
05/04/2019 00D29515 AC 
05/04/2019 00D30415 AC 
05/04/2019 00D30715 AC 
05/04/2019 00D30815 AC 
05/04/2019 00D31015 AC 
05/04/2019 00D41515 AC 
05/04/2019 00D49516 AC 
05/04/2019 00D63217 AC 
05/04/2019 00D63317 AC 
05/04/2019 00E01521 AC 
05/04/2019 00E01547 AC 
05/04/2019 00E01999 AC 
05/04/2019 00E02038 AC 
05/04/2019 00E02335 AC 
05/04/2019 00E02338 AC 
05/04/2019 00E16405 AC 
05/04/2019 00E66504 AC 
05/04/2019 00E66603 AC 
05/04/2019 00E66604 AC 
05/04/2019 02E01503 AC 
05/04/2019 83579302 AC 
05/04/2019 95490317 AC 
05/04/2019 97431017 AC 
05/04/2019 98408917 AC 
05/04/2019 98409217 AC 
05/04/2019 98485117 AC 
05/04/2019 98490416 AC 
05/04/2019 99060104 AC 
05/04/2019 99407714 AC 
05/04/2019 99446514 AC 
05/04/2019 00T26201 AD 
05/04/2019 00T76718 AD 
05/04/2019 00T77117 AD 
06/11/2019 00J90301 AA 
06/11/2019 01J32201 AA 
06/11/2019 97891601 AA 
06/11/2019 00406918 AB 
06/11/2019 00406015 AC 
06/11/2019 00406515 AC 
06/11/2019 00406715 AC 
06/11/2019 00406815 AC 
06/11/2019 00526416 AC 
06/11/2019 00571110 AC 
06/11/2019 00D28115 AC 
06/11/2019 00D28215 AC 
06/11/2019 00D28315 AC 
06/11/2019 00D28415 AC 
06/11/2019 00D29215 AC 
06/11/2019 00D29515 AC 
06/11/2019 00D30415 AC 
06/11/2019 00D30715 AC 
06/11/2019 00D30815 AC 
06/11/2019 00D31015 AC 
06/11/2019 00D41515 AC 
06/11/2019 00D49516 AC 
06/11/2019 00D63217 AC 
06/11/2019 00D63317 AC 
06/11/2019 00E01521 AC 
06/11/2019 00E01547 AC 
06/11/2019 00E01999 AC 
06/11/2019 00E02038 AC 
06/11/2019 00E02335 AC 
06/11/2019 00E02338 AC 
06/11/2019 00E16405 AC 
06/11/2019 00E66504 AC 
06/11/2019 00E66603 AC 
06/11/2019 00E66604 AC 
06/11/2019 02E01503 AC 
06/11/2019 83579302 AC 
06/11/2019 95490317 AC 
06/11/2019 97431017 AC 
06/11/2019 98408917 AC 
06/11/2019 98409217 AC 
06/11/2019 98485117 AC 
06/11/2019 98490416 AC 
06/11/2019 99060104 AC 
06/11/2019 99407714 AC 
06/11/2019 99446514 AC 
06/11/2019 00T26201 AC 
06/11/2019 00T76718 AC 
06/11/2019 00T77117 AC
```

And our PowerBI file has a few tables that return how many Project Officers have worked on between 1-2 grant families, between 3-9, and more than 20, for a certain upload date. We've checked those figures and filters and they work.

Our next goal is to present the difference between the upload dates.

I created a DAX Measure like

```html
PO_Difference = Calculate(DistinctCount('Report'[Project Officer]),'Report'[Upload Date] = date (2019,11,6))-Calculate(DistinctCount('Report'[Project Officer]),'Report'[Upload Date] = date (2019,4,5))
'
```

And it's not returning our expected result. If I break the formula into two, both calculate portions return the expected result if I apply their relevant filter, but my hunch is the filters are distorting what the formula returns for each section, and I'm at a loss how else to approach this. Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using variables?

```
PO_Difference =
VAR x = Calculate(DistinctCount('Report'[Project Officer]),'Report'[Upload Date] = date (2019,11,6))

VAR y = Calculate(DistinctCount('Report'[Project Officer]),'Report'[Upload Date] = date (2019,4,5))

return x -y
```